# Is there any recommended partition layout for Ubuntu 16.04 aimed to be the only OS for a production environment machine?

Tags: partitioning

Ubuntu is being considered for adoption in an electronic projects production environment. Since there is a requirement for the entire environment to be always updated, cache for packages and kernels are always getting bigger. Frequent changes are also required, what could impact in partition layout.

I would like to know if there is any recommended partition layout(size, partition types, mounting points, etc) for Ubuntu 16.04 in this case.

Comment: I suggest at least /, swap and /home, with type ext4, swap and ext4, but it's a personal testing. Other people would suggest also /boot, but I forget about it and gets full pretty fast with kernel updates.

Comment: If you're worried about (package) caches filling up drive space, you might want to look into having `/var` on a separate partition. ext4 should be fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your using or how your using it. Are you using a live cd/usb? Are you using it as your main OS? Is there any other OS(s) in the HDD/cd/usb/(....ext) you are placing it? Any other files your trying to put on said medium that you want to keep? If not then just let the installer handle it. If you want to increase size needed later, or maybe downsize/modify the partitions' later, then they have a box to check otherwise let it handle it from there.

If you are adding it alongside another OS, then partitioning from the other OS, should make that partition space show up as a separate drive, so you will be able to see which one to let the auto install loose on. If you are just trying to go for the bare minimum then follow the recommended settings for your version on Ubuntu. Then add half as much swap space, and leave free space separating all the partitions.

Personally I prefer my 2Tb removable hard drive to take with me. /*the only issue I had with that is I use OSX and windows on my macbook pro 11.3 with bootcamp, but with rEFInd and a couple driver issues that got resolved.  everything works out smoothly with a nice boot screen to boot... pardon the pun  */

But anyway it is severely user dependent on what they use, I've provided the recommended requirements and minimum, with the minimum linking to the installation guide. Hope it helps, if not then please add more specifics of what your wanting to do, or use it for.

~
2.3. Memory and Disk Space Requirements

You must have at least 20MB of memory and 680MB of hard disk space to perform a normal installation. Note that these are fairly minimal numbers. For more realistic figures, see Section 3.4, “[Meeting Minimum Hardware Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/ch03s04.html)”.

Installation on systems with less memory or disk space available may be possible but is only advised for experienced users
~

// and yes I know grammar is atrocious